# Cocos2d-Android Sprite Slide-In and Slide-Out Animation

Tags: animation, slide, cocos2d-android

Can anyone please guide me how i can create an slide left and slide right animation in Cocos-2d Android, Thank you

I am new to Android-Cocos2d I have been working with IOS Cocos2d and Box2d but this is my first game with android and there isn't any good documentation for Cocos-2d Android so its hard to get things working. Can someone please help me with this, Thank you

Answer (score 2):

hi you can use the animation like this way which i use here i have to make animation to open curtain so here i am sharing you my code you can make any type of animation with use of plist file like this so hope its help fool for you all the best

This method invokes when The Background and Animation for Curtain Open is set...

```
    public void curtainAnimation(Object sender) {

            CCSpriteFrameCache.sharedSpriteFrameCache().addSpriteFrames("levelBackgrounds/level4_bg1.plist");

            CCSpriteFrameCache.sharedSpriteFrameCache().addSpriteFrames("levelBackgrounds/level4_bg2.plist");

            CCSpriteFrameCache.sharedSpriteFrameCache().addSpriteFrames("levelBackgrounds/level4_bg3.plist");

            CCAnimation curtainAnim = CCAnimation.animation("", 2.0f);

            for (int i = 300; i <= 500; i++) {
                curtainAnim.addFrame(CCSpriteFrameCache.sharedSpriteFrameCache().spriteFrameByName("curtain.0" + i + ".png"));
            }
            CCAction curtainOpenAction = CCAnimate.action(6, curtainAnim, false);
            curtainClose.runAction(curtainOpenAction);

        }
```

Comment: Hey Priyank, I have a plist file and ccz file. I used your code to make animation. But I dont know what is "curtainClose"? another question is where to put plist and ccz files?

Comment: hey hi curtainClose is just my method's name which i made for curtain animation from right to left direction,and plist file will be in assets folder and sry i have no idea about ccz files so sorry for that.

Comment: see here there is a one ex which i found where they use ccz file in android cocos2d here you can see they are adding ccz files in node:        _batchNode = CCSpriteBatchNode::batchNodeWithFile("Sprites.pvr.ccz");
this->addChild(_batchNode);
CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->addSpriteFramesWithFile("Sprites.plist");

Comment: And for android cocos2d there is no detail book you have to learn it from iphon book because the concept and logic will be same but syntax are different then android.

Comment: find one book which should be help full for you learning Cocos2d by rod strougo i used this book for reference and try to create find out some example for android cocos2d games there are so many links available on net you can Google it or i will also try to help you if possible..all the best

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can use this for left sliding
`moveLeft = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:0.7 position:ccp(10, 0)];`
For Right Sliding you can use this code
`moveRight = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:0.4 position:ccp(-200, 0)];`